Why do focused colors not work with OutlinedTextField DecorationBox?
I'm trying to customize the appearance of an OutlinedTextField in Jetpack Compose to have cyan text color and a 1dp thickness border. Despite setting the appropriate parameters, the text field remains black and the border doesn't change. Could anyone provide guidance on how to properly implement these customizations, especially regarding the focused colors?

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun MyTextField(
    value: String,
    interactionSource: InteractionSource = remember { MutableInteractionSource() },
    onValueChange: (String) -> Unit
) {
    BasicTextField(
        value = value,
        singleLine = true,
        onValueChange = onValueChange,
        decorationBox = { innerTextField ->
            OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.DecorationBox(
                value = value,
                innerTextField = innerTextField,
                enabled = true,
                singleLine = true,
                colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                    cursorColor = Color.Cyan,
                    focusedTextColor = Color.Cyan,
                    focusedBorderColor = Color.Cyan,
                ),
                interactionSource = interactionSource,
                visualTransformation = VisualTransformation.None,
                container = {
                    OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.ContainerBox(
                        enabled = true,
                        isError = false,
                        interactionSource = interactionSource,
                        colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
                            cursorColor = Color.Cyan,
                            focusedTextColor = Color.Cyan,
                            focusedBorderColor = Color.Cyan,
                        ),
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(10.dp),
                        focusedBorderThickness = 1.dp,
                        unfocusedBorderThickness = 1.dp
                    )
                }
            )
        }
    )
}



Here's a simpler way.
val focusedColor = Color.Cyan
val borderColor = Color.Cyan
val borderWidth = 1.dp

OutlinedTextField(
    modifier = Modifier
        .border(
            BorderStroke(
                width = borderWidth,
                color = borderColor
            ),
            shape = RoundedCornerShape(8.dp)
        ),
    value = value,
    onValueChange = onValueChange,
    singleLine = true,
    colors = OutlinedTextFieldDefaults.colors(
        disabledTextColor = focusedColor,
        cursorColor = focusedColor,
        focusedBorderColor = borderColor,
        unfocusedBorderColor = borderColor,
        focusedLabelColor = focusedColor,
        unfocusedLabelColor = focusedColor
    ),
)


It's not recommended to use modifier.border to customize the OutlinedTextField border, as it draws an additional border on top of the existing one.
